# How to get Crontab and Tar working together correctly

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, cron, tar

I've been playing around with getting crontab to run a tar command on a scheduled basis however it appears to not actually run the task at the intervals at all. 
The line of code I've put into my crontab file is as follows.

```
1 * * * * tar cvf backup.tar . >> ~/testcron.log
```

The tar command works by itself if I run it in terminal so I'm not sure why this doesn't run.

Thanks

Comment: Wrong site, not a programming question. Try http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux

Comment: And to answer your question: use full paths.

Comment: Don't forget when you use `>>` (append), your initial failed attempts will be at the top of the logfile (been there!), jump to bottom to see newest run output. I'd recommend making date/time-stamped log files with `...> cronlog.$(date +%Y%m%d.%H%M)` (you'll need to escape `%` chars in crontabs, like `\%Y\%m\%m...`). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things here which I can imagine being problematic:

1. If this is part of a file in `/etc/crontab.d` or part of `/etc/crontab`, cron expects a user name in the 6th column. So it would be something along the lines of:

   ```
   1 * * * * root tar cvf backup.tar . >> ~/testcron.log
   ```
2. You might want to replace `.` with a proper absolute path. I would not be sure what the current directory is when cron executes the cronjob, so just use an absolute path.

Comment: The username field depends on if the's talking about /etc/crontab or using `crontab -e`.

Comment: Statement 1 as it stands is wrong.

Comment: @KurtStutsman Oh I did not know about ``crontab -e``, I have always just used ``/etc/crontab{,.d/}``. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I've tried adding a direct path this is what the crontab looks like in crontab -e  `1 * * * * tar cvf /home/ollie/Desktop/backup.tar /home/ollie/Desktop >> ~/testcron.log`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this, it should be working.

Comment: Sometimes there will be problems expanding ~ through scripts. Try giving it `crontab -e 1 * * * * tar cvf /home/ollie/Desktop/backup.tar /home/ollie/Desktop >> /root/testcron.log`

Answer (score 0):

Unable to post as a comment

cron PATH variable may be different from your user PATH variable 
If this is the case, you will either have to specify the absolute path to the `tar` executable or export your local PATH to the crontab

More information [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work)